# Why I'm getting null exception on the Load/Save buttons?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

If I click on the "Save Conversations" or the "Load Conversations" button the variable _conversationTrigger is null.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditorInternal;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor(typeof(ConversationTrigger))]
public class ConversationTriggerEditor : Editor
{
    private ConversationTrigger _conversationTrigger;

    [SerializeField] private ReorderableList conversationsList;

    private SerializedProperty _conversations;

    private int _currentlySelectedConversationIndex = -1;
    private int newSize = 0;
    private Vector2 scrollPos;

    private readonly Dictionary<string, ReorderableList> _dialoguesListDict = new Dictionary<string, ReorderableList>();
    private readonly Dictionary<string, ReorderableList> _sentencesListDict = new Dictionary<string, ReorderableList>();


    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        if (GUILayout.Button("Edit Conversations"))
        {
            ConversationsEditorWindow myWindow = CreateInstance<ConversationsEditorWindow>();

            myWindow.minSize = new Vector2(1500, 900);
            myWindow.maxSize = new Vector2(1500, 900);
            myWindow.Init(serializedObject);

        }

        if (GUILayout.Button("Save Conversations"))
        {
            _conversationTrigger.SaveConversations();
        }

        if (GUILayout.Button("Load Conversations"))
        {
            Undo.RecordObject(_conversationTrigger, "Loaded conversations from JSON");
            _conversationTrigger.LoadConversations();
        }
    }
}
```

And the top of the ConversationsEdiotrWindow script the script is much longer. This is where I'm using the Init method to init the _conversationTrigger :

When using break point on the _conversationTrigger in the ConversationsEdiotrWindow it's fine but in the ConversationTriggerEditor script it's null.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditorInternal;
using UnityEngine;

public class ConversationsEditorWindow : EditorWindow
{
    public SerializedObject conversation = null;

    private ConversationTrigger _conversationTrigger;

    [SerializeField] private ReorderableList conversationsList;

    private SerializedProperty _conversations;

    private int _currentlySelectedConversationIndex = -1;
    private int newSize = 0;
    private Vector2 scrollPos;

    private readonly Dictionary<string, ReorderableList> _dialoguesListDict = new Dictionary<string, ReorderableList>();
    private readonly Dictionary<string, ReorderableList> _sentencesListDict = new Dictionary<string, ReorderableList>();

    private SerializedObject itemcopy;
    private string searchString = "";

    public void Init(SerializedObject _item)
    {
        // Copy the Item targetObject to not lose reference when you
        // click another element on the project window.
        itemcopy = new SerializedObject(_item.targetObject);
        conversation = itemcopy;

        // Other things to initialize the window

        const int width = 1500;
        const int height = 900;

        var x = (Screen.currentResolution.width - width) / 2;
        var y = (Screen.currentResolution.height - height) / 2;

        var window = GetWindow<ConversationsEditorWindow>();
        window.position = new Rect(x, y, width, height);

        _conversationTrigger = (ConversationTrigger)_item.targetObject;
        _conversations = itemcopy.FindProperty("conversations");
```

Comment: There's only one thing that can be null on those lines: `_conversationTrigger` which you never initialize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two different objects of type `ConverstationTrigger` in two different places. One is instantiated in `ConverstationsEditorWindow` while the other is `null` because there is no assignment in `ConversationTriggerEditor`.

By the looks of it, you want to use only one `ConverstationTrigger`. Perhaps there is a solution where you can inject the instance of `ConverstationTrigger` into the places you need it via the a constructor of some sort.